# javascript while loop which can be executed once in 10 ms

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

My javacript code uses asynchronous functions.

now the main loop waits for 2 counters to  be same .. which are being manipulated by those async functions.

code in main ..

```
while (counter1  != counter2) {
}
```

But i think this is taking all CPU and other async jobs are not able to proceed .

Is there any way so that the above while loop executes once in 10ms so that for the rest of the time
other async functions can run.

Comment: Please add more relevant code. The little piece of code here doesn't tell us anything about how the counters are working.

Comment: Why is the while loop there in the first place? You should not need it at all.

Comment: code is a bit long , but 1 counter keep tracks of number of async functions called, and the other keep count of number of asyn fucntions finished ..

Comment: @RakeshAgarwal Your while-loop and asynchronous functions all run within the same thread. This means that while your loop is running, no other code can be executed. See [Concurrency model and the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) for more information. But to be able to give you a decent solution, we really need more information. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```js
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if (counter1 === counter2) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  } else {
    // do stuff
  }
}, 10);
```